# Selenium 3 webdriver: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand c

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Before I updated Selenium and Firefox, may be 1 month ago everything works fine This happens after I updated to the last versions of Selenium WebDriver and Firefox. Selenium 3, FF 50.1.0. When I try to run this code

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class FirstTestCase {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String actualText;

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "destinationOfDriver/geckodriver-v0.13.0-win32/wires.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.arubabank.com/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("html/body/footer/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/section/a[3]"))).click();
```

After that I get this error massage in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException:     TypeError: invalid 'in' operand c
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20161208153507, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=38188, browserVersion=50.1.0, platformVersion=6.3, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: d17c4393-fa24-4650-bf8a-660895ed328d
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:315)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:302)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:651)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:644)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
at automationFramework.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:32)
```

Comment: Does it happen also if you use different addresses as the argument of your `driver.get()` call ?

Comment: For example www.iak.nl give the same result, but www.gmail.com doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you have some idea about what `invalid 'in' operand c` refers to (I don't). I can only speculate that `JavascriptException` is thrown to indicate a problem with the Javascript code found in the page, in which case your code would be supposed to just catch and handle it as such; but it's only a guess; maybe you can check the doc to see if that is actually a meaning of `JavascriptException`. Otherwise if I were you I would try to ask the FirefoxDriver people, if they have a forum or something. If you do and you get some useful info please post a link to that here.

Comment: Did you try to run the code from my example?

Comment: If you are talking to me, no, I didn't, why ?

Comment: Because one of the possibilities is that the problem could be in my network. And if it works in different networks then I should dig into that.

Comment: I am not going to download and install Firefox Driver and make your code compilable and test. I was trying to help you off the top of my head, I have other things to do. As a suggestion you might try to identify your element in another way rather than by xpath; perhaps by attribute; f.ex., it looks like your element is an anchor, so you might try to get to it by its `href` attribute. Keeping in mind that when you change the web address to another page of course the page contains different elements so you should also change your element search.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.